# Angular FormControl valueChanges doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I want to get one of my forms ("family") value if changed by subscribing but it seems something is wrong because I got nothing on my console's log.

```ts
import { Component , AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="frm1">
<input type="text" formControlName="name" >
<input type="text" formControlName="family">
</form>
`,

})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  frm1 : FormGroup;

  constructor( fb:FormBuilder){
    this.frm1 = fb.group({
      name : [],
      family: []
    });
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    var search = this.frm1.controls.family;
    search.valueChanges.subscribe( x => console.log(x));
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `change()` event handler in your HTML's input fields ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `get` method on form variable `frm1`. And use `ngOnInit()` instead of `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {  
   this.frm1.get('family').valueChanges.subscribe( x => console.log(x));
}
```

Comment: Place the code within `ngOnInit()` and try. There is no reason to do within `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: thanks now its working, may i know why AfterViewInit had problem!!

Comment: That was a workaround that I suggested, there is no reason to watch form control in`AfterViewInit`, since you are working on model-driven forms and you have all the form control names in place. So ideal place would be onInit().

Comment: I came across this issue because I am using this feature with a ngFor with async pipe, so it automagically subscribes and everything works just fine.
Now I am using another one with a formControl and I forgot to subscribe :(
Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: Prefer `rxjs` other features (`startWith` and `map` for example) rather than using `subscribe`: `this.control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), map(opt => this.isMatch(name)));`

Answer (score 3):

> Try this:

```
import { Component , AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `<h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form [formGroup]="frm1">
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" >
        <input type="text" formControlName="family">
        </form>`})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{ 

frm1 : FormGroup;

constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formInit();
    this.formSet();
}

formInit(): void {
    this.frm1 = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [''],
        family['']
    })
}

formSet(): void {
    const editForm = {
        name: 'test-name',
        family: 'test familty',
    };
    this.frm1.patchValue(editForm) 
}

ngAfterViewInit(){  
this.frm1 .controls.family.valueChanges.subscribe(
       () => {
              console.log(this.frm1 .controls.family.value)
             }
        )
      }
}
```

Comment: i have tested in my project: it works: what error you getting

Comment: you have to have functions for form init and set. otherthan this. you can use .next() method to  detect change

Comment: i thought: you nedd to edit form after, thats why suggest form init and set

Answer (score 3):

The question already uses subscribe but just in case somebody like me lands here after reading the title. `valueChanges` was also not working for me but for some other reason.

I was using material stepper and auto complete for my project. The sample code on their website, filters the data within map but it did not work.

```
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), map(value => this._filter(value)));
```

However subscribing to the `valueChange` worked and filtered the data.

```
this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')).subscribe(value => this.filteredOptions = of(this._filter(value)));
```