# Value changes is not getting called in Reactive Form using Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, valuechangelistener

i am using reactive form for dropdown and i want the value changes to be called when my dropdown value changes, i have implemented like this

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.employeerosterForm = this._formbuilder.group({
      drpDomain: [''],
      drpPlatform: [{ value: this.platformInitialValue, disabled: this.platformControlDisabled }],
      drpApplication: [{ value: this.applicationInitialValue, disabled: this.applicationControlDisabled }],
      drpIndividual: [{ value: this.individualInitialValue, disabled: this.individualControlDisabled }]
    })

 this.employeerosterForm.controls.drpDomain
      .valueChanges
      .subscribe(domain => {
        alert();
      });
  }
```

but when i change the value in dropdown, the value changes is not getting called eventough i have subscribed. what is wrong?

I even tried to use this on ngOninit()

```
 this.employeerosterForm.get('drpDomain')
    .valueChanges
      .subscribe(domain => {
        alert();
      });
```

but it is not working

**EDIT 1**

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" formControlname='drpDomain'>
              <option>Select Domain</option>
              <option *ngFor='let d of domain' [value]='d.DOMAINNAME'>{{d.DOMAINNAME}}</option>
            </select>
```

.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeControls();
    this.interactionWatchDog();
  }

 interactionWatchDog() {
    this.employeerosterForm.get('drpDomain')
      .valueChanges
      .subscribe(domain => {
        alert();
      });
  }

initializeControls() {
    this.employeerosterForm = this._formbuilder.group({
      drpDomain: [''],
      drpPlatform: [{ value: this.platformInitialValue, disabled: this.platformControlDisabled }],
      drpApplication: [{ value: this.applicationInitialValue, disabled: this.applicationControlDisabled }],
      drpIndividual: [{ value: this.individualInitialValue, disabled: this.individualControlDisabled }]
    })
  }
```

Comment: could you share html part?

Comment: If possible please provide a stackblitz of the same

Comment: i have updated my question, please take a look

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Form Control valueChanges not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602410/angular-form-control-valuechanges-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here `formControlname` in your template, possibly because of that it doesn't work:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName='drpDomain'>
  <option>Select Domain</option>
  <option *ngFor='let d of domain' [value]='d.DOMAINNAME'> 
    {{d.DOMAINNAME}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/value-changes-is-not-getting-called-in-reactive-form-using-angu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want:

```
this.employeerosterForm.valueChanges
```

or

```
this.employeerosterForm.get('controlName').valueChanges
```

Also make sure your form in the template is properly wired up to match the class, it could be orphaned in some way.